# JQ datepicker won't work

Tags: jquery, html

I have this example that works as it should:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />

</div>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {  
    }
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And I want to implement it on another page. But it won't work and I'm getting no errors.  This is the header of my other page:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">      
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" /> 
    <script src="js/leslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: why are you loading 2 different versions of jquery? if the plugin works with jquery `1.9.1` but not `1.11.3` then that might be the answer

Comment: Which lines are getting two different versions?

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` and `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Beucase I might be blind. Sorry for the late reply, but meanwhile I decided not to use the JQ datepicker and used http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ instead.